# unable to get results from jsoup while giving post request

Tags: java, c#, .net, jsoup, scrape

This is the code snippet , it always returns error page

```
    try {
        String url = "http://kepler.sos.ca.gov/";
        Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .execute();

        Document responseDocument = response.parse();

        Element eventValidation = responseDocument.select("input[name=__EVENTVALIDATION]").first();
        Element viewState = responseDocument.select("input[name=__VIEWSTATE]").first();
        response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .data("__VIEWSTATE", viewState.attr("value"))
                .data("__EVENTVALIDATION", eventValidation.attr("value"))
                .data("ctl00_content_placeholder_body_BusinessSearch1_TextBox_NameSearch", "escrow")  // <- search 
                .data("ctl00_content_placeholder_body_BusinessSearch1_RadioButtonList_SearchType", "Corporation Name")
                .data("ctl00_content_placeholder_body_BusinessSearch1_Button_Search", "Search")

                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .followRedirects(true)
                .execute();
        Document document = response.parse(); //search results
        System.out.println(document);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I got the request response from net panel of firebug and sent the same.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your android version, that code will give a "NetworkOnMainThreadExcpetion" if you try to run it directly from a button click or something like that.  On honeycomb or later, you have to do network access from a separate explicit thread or a AsyncTask.

From my debugging, you need to add some cookies.  That's included below.  Also, a couple of your form fields were missing dollar signs, and there were some blank form fields being passed that were empty but the server might expect, so I included those too.

For future reference, I recommend the tool [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler%20Fiddler) to debug issues like this if you're not using it already.

```
class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(Void... params) {
        long totalSize = 0;

        try {
            String url = "http://kepler.sos.ca.gov/";
            Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();

            Document responseDocument = response.parse();
            Map<String, String> loginCookies = response.cookies();


            Element eventValidation = responseDocument.select("input[name=__EVENTVALIDATION]").first();
            String validationKey = eventValidation.attr("value");

            Element viewState = responseDocument.select("input[name=__VIEWSTATE]").first();
            String viewStateKey = viewState.attr("value");

            response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .cookies(loginCookies)
                    .data("__EVENTTARGET", "")
                    .data("__EVENTARGUMENT", "")
                    .data("__LASTFOCUS", "")
                    .data("__VIEWSTATE", viewStateKey)
                    .data("__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED", "")
                    .data("__EVENTVALIDATION", validationKey)
                    .data("ctl00$content_placeholder_body$BusinessSearch1$TextBox_NameSearch", "aaa")  // <- search
                    .data("ctl00$content_placeholder_body$BusinessSearch1$RadioButtonList_SearchType", "Corporation Name")
                    .data("ctl00$content_placeholder_body$BusinessSearch1$Button_Search", "Search")

                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .followRedirects(true)
                    .execute();
            Document document = response.parse(); //search results
            System.out.println(document);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return totalSize;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
    }
}
```

You would actually execute that code using something like:

```
TestAsyncTask t = new TestAsyncTask();
t.execute();
```

To get Page 2, you would have to include the following headers.  This is pseudocode, obviously, you'd have to convert it to .data calls:

```
__EVENTTARGET = ctl00$content_placeholder_body$SearchResults1$GridView_SearchResults_Corp
__EVENTARGUMENT = Page$2
```

And you still need the other headers ( __VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED blank, __VIEWSTATE as above) and cookies as above.

Comment: I am writing them in normal Java main() method. I am not getting any exception , but not getting any results too, if you open that website and see the results , you will get the real picture of what am I looking for.

Comment: So what version of Android are you using?  And what exception/error are you seeing?

Comment: I am writing them in normal Java main() method. I am not getting any exception , but not getting any results too, if you open that website and see the results , you will get the real picture of what am I looking for. –

Comment: So you're trying to figure out what parameters to pass to actually get a different result from the web server?

Comment: see modified code above.  I think you were missing the cookies, and also some of your form fields were missing dollar signs.  The modified version I posted above returns actual search results.  And I broke out a couple variables into separate strings so I could debug it more easily, but the functionality is the same.  Finally, there were a few more form fields that were blank, but included in the post when done from a web page, so I included those too.

Comment: Its working but another problem comes now, if I want to navigate to second page then, I gave .data("__EVENTTARGET", "ctl00$content_placeholder_body$SearchResults1$GridView_SearchResults_Corp")
                .data("__EVENTARGUMENT", "Page$2") but it returns the first page result only.

Comment: Updated with some page 2 info, but I strongly recommend you grab Fiddler and get used to to using it to inspect HTTP traffic.

Comment: No I tried the code above also tried to follow the path as per site but no luck

Comment: ...sigh.  That web site is annoying me.  I'll have to debug it more later if I can.  Might be some javascript that modifies some value on the click, but fiddler claims that's the correct params.

Comment: yes I too checked fiddler and as per your answer fiddler does the same, These govt. sites really sucks.

Comment: I wasn't able to get the second page to work.  You might want to try opening a new question just for the second page.  It has to be close to what we have here, but for whatever reason it wasn't working the same as the first page.