# How to redirect to a webpage that accepts post requests?

Tags: html, jsp, jsoup

I am working on a project where I need to scrap data in JSOUP and the show as HTML in my webpage and on clicking view more I am forwarding to the scrapped URL, issue is where GET url's are working fine but POST request for aspx are not working as it expects some **__EVENTVALIDATION**, etc,.. as input in form.
The webpage is [kepler.sos.ca.gov](http://kepler.sos.ca.gov), if you click on Corporation Name then enter ESCROW, then submit, some results will come up, which I am able to do in JSOUP, but unable to redirect using `javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$content_placeholder_body$SearchResults1$GridView_SearchResults_Corp','DetailCorp$0').`

Please advice.

Comment: add your code to your question, not to my answer please.

Comment: plz check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943477/unable-to-get-results-from-jsoup-while-giving-post-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a answer over here : [unable to get results from jsoup while giving post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943477/unable-to-get-results-from-jsoup-while-giving-post-request)

`Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();

```
        Document responseDocument = response.parse();
        Map<String, String> loginCookies = response.cookies();


        Element eventValidation = responseDocument.select("input[name=__EVENTVALIDATION]").first();
        String validationKey = eventValidation.attr("value");

        Element viewState = responseDocument.select("input[name=__VIEWSTATE]").first();
        String viewStateKey = viewState.attr("value");

        response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .cookies(loginCookies)
                .data("__EVENTTARGET", "")
                .data("__EVENTARGUMENT", "")
                .data("__LASTFOCUS", "")
                .data("__VIEWSTATE", viewStateKey)
                .data("__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED", "")
                .data("__EVENTVALIDATION", validationKey)
                .data("ctl00$content_placeholder_body$BusinessSearch1$TextBox_NameSearch", "aaa")  // <- search
                .data("ctl00$content_placeholder_body$BusinessSearch1$RadioButtonList_SearchType", "Corporation Name")
                .data("ctl00$content_placeholder_body$BusinessSearch1$Button_Search", "Search")

                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .followRedirects(true)
                .execute();
        Document document = response.parse(); //search results
        System.out.println(document);`
```

Answer (score 1):

JSoup is not a browser. It does not interpret JavaScript and you can't fire a POST request through a JavaScript link.

JSoup is however quite capable doing POST requests. To use JSoup here, you need to figure out how the actual request is built by the JavaScript. You then can run the same algorithm coded in Java and create the link and do the POST request.

An easier way of achieving what you want is maybe a switch in technology. You can use [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) for example, which allows to "remote control" a real browser, which should have no problem running the JavaScript of that page.

Comment: I am redirecting to the page from which I scrapped the data earlier, and the redirection is done using post request , selenium is for automation, but I need to redirect to kepler.sos.ca.gov using post request. Did you understand my approach

Comment: I guess I did not understand. And I still have no clue what you mean by "the redirection is done using post request ". Please explain exactly what you do and where you are stuck. (This is also true for your other unanswered questions about the same subject)

Comment: Ok ,let me explain step wise, first open my web page, input some value, for eg: Facebook, enter search, I will search in kepler.sos.ca.gov using post request using jsoup, then will show the results in UI using ajax/html,etc. then when user clicks view details ,I need to redirect him to the page from where I scrapped using jsoup

Comment: I have added the code above that fails even in standalone version

Comment: The site you are trying to scrape has implemented precautions against exactly that type of (mis)use (crsf tokens, btaa etc.). Did you ask permission to do that with your app?

Comment: How to do that? Can you suggest me please.